# Не могу вывести каптчу

Tags: php

Есть код

```
    include_once ("./data/php_pages/plugin_add.php");   #Рекламные вставки
       $title="Форма заказа трансформаторов";

       $echo=<<<EOF
    <table>
Первая табличка
</table>

<table>
вторая табличка
</table>
EOF;
```

Между первой и второй табличкой мне нужно вставить код  с выводом каптчи. 
Как это можно сделать . Может кто то сталкивался с таким.
Например, есть файлик captch.php

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
$pos = rand(0, 36);

$str .= $string {
$pos
};
}
$img_handle = ImageCreate(60, 22) or die("Створити зображення не можливо");
$back_color = ImageColorAllocate($img_handle, 102, 102, 153);
$txt_color = ImageColorAllocate($img_handle, 255, 255, 255);
ImageString($img_handle, 31, 5, 0, $str, $txt_color);
Imagepng($img_handle);
session_start();
$_SESSION['img_number'] = $str;
```

далее вывожу

```
    include_once ("./data/php_pages/plugin_add.php");   #Рекламные вставки
       $title="Форма заказа трансформаторов";

       $echo=<<<EOF
    <table>
Первая табличка
    </table>
<img src="<?php include ('captcha.php');?>">
    <input name="captcha" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $captcha ;?>">
    <input name="pr" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6"></p>

<table>
вторая табличка
</table>
EOF;
```

это не работает .
версия php 5.2

Comment: `session_start()` всегда нужно вызывать первой строкой. Как минимум, до вывода, а у вас сначала вывод, потом старт сессии, который не происходит.

Comment: тут проблема с выводом картинки не показывает картинку.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что php 5.2 уже 8 лет как не поддерживается?

Comment: да я понимаю, это не от меня зависит